# BAT script - how to automatically insert additional arguments?

Tags: winforms, authentication, batch-file

I want to write a simple bat script but I cannot deal with one thing.

I run a command and it gives few messages and it's waiting for my login. I want to write a script which will do it.

For example, I run a command:

```
myCommand.bat
```

and it gives:

```
msg1...
msg2...
...
type your login:_
```

Now, I have to put my login.

How can I do it automatically?

BAT script is the best way for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably *can* solve this by either

- placing your username and/or password directly in myCommand.bat
- placing your username and/or password in a file "myPassword.txt" and using redirection: `<myPassowrd.txt myCommand.bat`

But, you probably ***should not*** do either of those for security reasons.

**Addendum:**

If your batch script is calling an executable that is prompting for the login credentials, you may have 2 options

- The executable may have a command line option(s) that allows you to specify username
  and/or password. You would have to research your executable to find out what they are.
- If the executable is not expecting any other input, you might be able to pipe the username and/or password into the program. For example, if the program asks for username and then asks for password, something like this *might* work:

  `(echo yourName&echo yourPassword)|yourProgram.exe`

Security concerns still apply